# Restful API,the TPS Slow down

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat7, undertow, tps

My simple object like this:

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>  
            <exclusion>  
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>  
            </exclusion>  
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
    </dependency>  
</dependencies>
<!-- Package as an executable jar -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The Class like this:

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class Example {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        return "Hello World!__";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);
    }
}
```

Execute the command:

```
/home/gdct/jdk1.8.0_152/bin/java -server -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MetaspaceSize=128M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -jar /home/gdct/abc/aembedjar.jar --server.port=9998
```

At first,the TPS is 3600,But After a few minutes,THE TPS is 1500.(Slow down)

Please help me,how to keep the TPS is 3500(or other number) or so ???

**note:** I had test a webservice api, it can keep the tps.

Comment: embedded tomcat is also.

Comment: Have you taken a memory dump or did you check with CPU utilization

Comment: CPU:80%,mem:13%

Comment: cpu cores : 4,MemTotal:        7994772 kB

Comment: where I execute a webservice api, the CPU usage is 205%

Comment: take a memory dump and analyse if you are receiving any blocked thred

Comment: As CPU is high, you need to take thread dump

Comment: This is the thread dump 
 https://github.com/lingo169/testweb/blob/master/threads9.txt  , have something wrong ??

Comment: check this thread dump analysis .  http://fastthread.io/my-thread-report.jsp?p=c2hhcmVkLzIwMTgvMDMvOS8tLVVudGl0bGVkIDIudHh0LS0yMC0xOC00Ng==